# How to find the distance traveled by user in a particular year?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UserId, SRC, DST, Mode, Dist, Year
1,CHN,IND,airplane,200,1990
2,IND,CHN,airplane,200,1991
3,IND,CHN,airplane,200,1992
4,RUS,IND,airplane,200,1990
5,CHN,RUS,airplane,200,1992
6,AUS,PAK,airplane,200,1991
```

I want to find the total distance traveled by a user in a particular year.

```
Ex: <Id> <Distance> <year>
     1  200 1991
     1  600 1993
     2  400 1991
     2  200 1992
```

How do I write query for this?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` and `SUM`. Btw, always ensure that the sample data posted and expected output correlate.

Comment: I tried this one - select holidays.id, sum(holidays.distance), holidays.year  from  holidays group by holidays.id order by holidays.id ASC;   And i am getting total value in all the years the user traveled. Like: 1|800|1993
2|600|1991
3|600|1991
4|600|1990

Comment: in the output you are grouping by which column ??

Comment: group by holidays.id

Comment: General advice: always have expected result that matches the sample table data. Your table has the UserId's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. But the expected result only includes user 1 and 2. Is that what you want?

Comment: No. User 1 traveled total distance in 1991, User 1 traveled total distance in 1992 ... Like wise for every user. There are 5 years (1990 to 1994) in some cases the user may not traveled in particular year. The expected output is user traveled total distance in year wise.

Comment: @Neha I suspect that there is no userid column in your holidays table. How does someone get to know which holday id belongs to a specific user ?

Comment: in my table, the id represents the user id. The first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add holidays.year in `group by` clause

```
select holidays.id, sum(holidays.distance) as totaldistance, holidays.year 
from holidays 
group by holidays.id ,holidays.year
order by holidays.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your groupings are UserID and Year so:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(Dist), Year
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID,Year
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT USERID, YEAR, SUM (DIST)
FROM TABLE_USER_DISTANCE
GROUP BY USERID, YEAR;
```

Comment: Add explanatory text, and (where applicable) code comments.